# How to use collision in OimoJS with BABYLONJS

Tags: collision-detection, collision, babylonjs

I'm trying to use collision Mesh with other mesh
the problem in CanonJS it's support sphere only and when i use OimoJS Mesh collision not work correctly
this example by BABYLONJS:

https://playground.babylonjs.com/#3B3135#1

I'm trying to change `scene.enablePhysics();`

to `scene.enablePhysics(new BABYLON.Vector3(0,-9.81, 0), new BABYLON.OimoJSPlugin());`

but when i change it something wrong happen to the Mesh collision

i think it give sphere or box collision to the Mesh imported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not fully understand your question but here are my comments:

CanonJS supports numerous types of impostors (not only sphere) and in fact it's my favourite physics engine. A comparison of different types of impostors that physics engines support is presented in the following link:
https://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/using_the_physics_engine

If you are only concerned with collision detection only and the precision is important to you, you can set the precise property to true. The following link describes how you can do that:

https://doc.babylonjs.com/babylon101/intersect_collisions_-_mesh

If you would like to know how to use Oimo.js with Babylon.js, you can refer to the following great article:

https://blog.raananweber.com/2016/09/06/webgl-car-physics-using-babylon-js-and-oimo-js/